# PostgreSQL EDB installer's post-install step fails

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, enterprisedb

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 64bit.
When trying to install PostgreSQL 9.6 by [EDB installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#linux), and it fails on `post-install step`:

[image: error message screenshot]

Below is that part of the log file, where something went wrong.

```
Initialising the database cluster (this may take a few minutes)...
Executing /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/installer/server/initcluster.sh "postgres" "postgres" "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6" "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/data" 5432 ru_UA.utf8
Script exit code: 1

Script output:
 Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Script stderr:
 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/.config’: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/.config/budgie-desktop/firstrun': No such file or directory
-su: 28: /etc/profile.d/10-budgie-desktop.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Error running /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/installer/server/initcluster.sh "postgres" "postgres" "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6" "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/data" 5432 ru_UA.utf8: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/.config’: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/.config/budgie-desktop/firstrun': No such file or directory
-su: 28: /etc/profile.d/10-budgie-desktop.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 The database cluster initialisation failed.
```

**Notes**:

- installer was launched with `root` privileges (it raises an error on startup if not).
- after installation fail, `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6` directory exists.

How to complete cluster initialization without EDB installer?
How to fix installer?
What is the proper way to report EDB installer issues?

Comment: `cannot create directory ‘/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/.config’: Permission denied`  says it all. (You probably must install as root, or at least as postgres. RTFM is your friend;-)

Comment: BTW: do you have an existing`/opt/....` directory? Does it exist *after* the failed install?

Comment: @wildplasser with `root`, exists even after.

Comment: i have the same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: @AchmadNaufalSyafiq no, I didn't. I'm just using docker for any kind of such software. It's easier to use and in this way, it doesn't depend on your machine.